# Use of 全て（すべて）in a sentence

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese, japanese-to-english

Would it be accurate to say:
**すべてが高かった**ので何も買いませんでした。
to mean "I did not buy anything because everything was expensive."
Is the phrasing correct? And is the use of the particle ”が” accurate or should I use ”は” instead? (**すべては高かった**ので何も買いませんでした。）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should say すべてが高かったので何も買いませんでした。

If you say すべては高かったので何も買いませんでした。
We’ll think “Something besides すべて(everything) isn’t expensive? What do you mean?”

But we usually say 全て高かったので何も買いませんでした。 and 全部高かったので何も買いませんでした。
You don’t have to use が.